# Azure Queue too slow - About 2 minutes until the message is being picked up by Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure

I have a WCF on a Web Role and then a Worker Role to process the messages added to an azure queue by the WCF.

I am doing the following :

```
var queue = queueStorage.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

var message = new CloudQueueMessage(string.Format("{0},{1}", pWord,processed));
queue.AddMessage(message);
```

Then I want to wait until the message has been processed, but this is taking too long, an average of 2 minutes for one message!!

On my worker role I have the following :

This is my onStart method :

```
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        inputQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");
```

And then on my Run method :

```
while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Retrieve and process a new message from the queue.
                    msg = inputQueue.GetMessage();
                    if (msg != null)
                    {
                        result = processMessage(msg);
```

On my processMessage method :

```
var messageParts = msg.AsString.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            var word = messageParts[0];
            var processed = Convert.ToBoolean(messageParts[2]);
            word = "recibido";
            processed = true;
            addMessageToQueue2(userId,processed);
            return 1;
```

Add message to queue is :

```
var queue = outputQueue.GetQueueReference("myQueue");
            var message = new CloudQueueMessage(string.Format("{0},{1}", pWord, pProcessed));
            queue.AddMessage(message);
```

Im fairly new to queues but I think this should work and be faster than 2 minutes per message..any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Just checking: In that very last block of code, you're creating a reference to `myQueue`. Is that the actual queue name, or is that a typo? Queue names must be all lower-case.

Comment: Also, since your message is "{0},{1}", your line: var processed = Convert.ToBoolean(messageParts[2]); - should be generating an error as messageParts should only be accessible as messageParts[0] or messageParts[1] - are you falling into a try/catch?

Comment: that was just to replace my actual queue name...yes I learnt queue names were only lowercase the hard way :)

Comment: that is not generating anny exceptions viperguynaz

Comment: Also: queues absolutely don't have a 2-minute delay on messages. Assuming you turn off Nagle algorithm (see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/06/25/nagle-s-algorithm-is-not-friendly-towards-small-requests.aspx) for details around ServicePointManager class), you'll see a phenomenal transaction rate (up to 2,000 per second).

Comment: @viperguynaz - check out the documentation for `Split()` - there will be a placeholder in the array for the delineator as well, so the data will be in `[0]` and `[2]`.

Comment: Also, are you adding the message back to the queue in processMessage(msg) - after the worker role retrieves the message and processes the message, you should delete the message, i.e. Queue.DeleteMessage(msg)

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx - Delimiter characters are not included in the elements of the returned array.

Comment: In your Run method I hope you are not doing a `Thread.Sleep(120*1000);` inside the `while (true) {...}`

Comment: nope, currently I am testing without any sleep

Comment: disabling Nable algorithm made it possible to process more than 400 messages a second, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code looks to be adding the same message back to the queue.  GetMessage only makes the message unaccessible for 30 seconds (while you process the message) and allows for worker role failures.  Read [How to use the Queue Storage Service, specifically How to: De-queue the next message](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/#get-message) for details.  Flow for worker role:

- GetMessage
- ProcessMessage
- If successful, DeleteMessage else reattempt processing.

Also note, unless you are calling string.split with StringSplitOptions.None, you aren't getting getting placeholders and your result array is only 2 elements long - read more at [String.Split Method (Char[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx)

Comment: Im gonna give a try to this lets see